# Specifying parameters in Cypher queries from Java

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher

I am using an embedded Neo4j database from Java. Given a property-value pair (e.g., ('id', '29384234'), I would like to find the corresponding unique node using Cypher. I've looked at a number of examples in the [Neo4j documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-query-lang.html), but all of them assume some static id or key-value pair to identify the starting node. The Cypher Java API describes the [`execute(String query,Map<String,Object> params)`](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-cypher/1.8/apidocs/index.html#execute%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map%29) method, but does not give any examples.

How are parameter values referenced in the query?

Alternatively, is there a better way to get at a single node given a (property name, value) pair that uniquely identifies the node?

Comment: I have better question)) 
How they want that i run this query where is the params is 3 different ids with same key?))
Match (a:A{id:1}),(b:B{id:2}),
Create (a)-[r:REL {id:3}]->(b)

Answer (score 1):

It was too obvious: the answer is on the [Parameters](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-parameters.html) page.